# How to view embedded image in a CSS file

Tags: css, image, png, embedded-resource

I came across this background image in a CSS file.

How can I view it?

```
background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFIAAAB3CAYAAACQTRce
AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAABx0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgR
mlyZXdvcmtzIENTNXG14zYAAAmZSURBVHic7Zt/bB... BIG SNIP ...V3JGCkIKVIQUqQgpEhBSJGCk
CIFIUUKQubZCELm2QhC5tkIQubZCELm2QhC5tkIQubZCELm2QhC5tkIQubZFEno2LWC+6Jkno0g5HdtQU
iRgpAiBSFFCkKKFIQUKQiV3FYMycK4oysVeOVuBSQOF8i5KojcjC8IGSMFIUUKQooUhBQpCClSEFKkIKR
IQUiRgpAiBfFfWn5d1Y2PJI0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=)
```

I tried to paste everything between `"iVBOR..."` and `"5CYII="` in a file and renamed it `image.png` - but that didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you paste everything from "`data: ...`" through the `=` into the Firefox address bar it will draw it for you.

Or put something like this into your HTML:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

Comment: Didn't know that Firefox would render the data uri, cool. This a standard capability of modern browsers?

Comment: Thank you, yes pasting into Firefox worked.  That's a neat trick

Comment: @Nathan: I'm not sure. My initial guess is yes, modern browsers should handle these encoded data streams to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

The PNG data is encoded using base64 in order to textually represent it. You would have to decode the base64 before saving to a file. But, the HTML code required to simply view this in a browser should be trivial:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div {
        background: ...
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You may have to tweak the size of the `div`.

Comment: Better yet, just go to jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the data into a PNG file won't work, because it's base-64 encoded. I see two possibilities:

1. Decode the data and save that to a file.
2. Create an HTML page with a `<div>` which uses that CSS style, then open the page in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

(function(){window.latencyTrackerTimes={clientSideStartMs:Date.now()};})();(function(){function _DumpException(b){window.console.error(b.stack)};var f=this,m=Date.now||function(){return+new Date};function aa(b,d){var a=["LOWLIFE_wizbind"],c=d||f;a[0]in c||!c.execScript||c.execScript("var "+a[0]);for(var e;a.length&&(e=a.shift());)a.length||void 0===b?c[e]?c=c[e]:c=c[e]={}:c[e]=b};function ba(b,d){if(null===d)return!1;if("contains"in b&&1==d.nodeType)return b.contains(d);if("compareDocumentPosition"in b)return b==d||!!(b.compareDocumentPosition(d)&16);for(;d&&b!=d;)d=d.parentNode;return d==b};var v={};function ca(b,d){return function(a){a||(a=window.event);return d.call(b,a)}}function y(b){b=b.target||b.srcElement;!b.getAttribute&&b.parentNode&&(b=b.parentNode);return b}var C="undefined"!=typeof navigator&&/Macintosh/.test(navigator.userAgent),da="undefined"!=typeof navigator&&!/Opera/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&/WebKit/.test(navigator.userAgent),ea={A:1,INPUT:1,TEXTAREA:1,SELECT:1,BUTTON:1};function fa(){this._mouseEventsPrevented=!0}
var E={A:13,BUTTON:0,CHECKBOX:32,COMBOBOX:13,GRIDCELL:13,LINK:13,LISTBOX:13,MENU:0,MENUBAR:0,MENUITEM:0,MENUITEMCHECKBOX:0,MENUITEMRADIO:0,OPTION:0,RADIO:32,RADIOGROUP:32,RESET:0,SUBMIT:0,TAB:0,TREE:13,TREEITEM:13};function F(b){return(b.getAttribute("type")||b.tagName).toUpperCase()in ga}function G(b){return(b.getAttribute("type")||b.tagName).toUpperCase()in ha}
var ga={CHECKBOX:!0,OPTION:!0,RADIO:!0},ha={COLOR:!0,DATE:!0,DATETIME:!0,"DATETIME-LOCAL":!0,EMAIL:!0,MONTH:!0,NUMBER:!0,PASSWORD:!0,RANGE:!0,SEARCH:!0,TEL:!0,TEXT:!0,TEXTAREA:!0,TIME:!0,URL:!0,WEEK:!0},ia={A:!0,AREA:!0,BUTTON:!0,DIALOG:!0,IMG:!0,INPUT:!0,LINK:!0,MENU:!0,OPTGROUP:!0,OPTION:!0,PROGRESS:!0,SELECT:!0,TEXTAREA:!0};function H(){this.j=[];this.a=[];this.c=[];this.i={};this.b=null;this.f=[]}var ja="undefined"!=typeof navigator&&/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent),I=String.prototype.trim?function(b){return b.trim()}:function(b){return b.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,"")},ka=/\s*;\s*/;function la(b,d){return function(a){var c;var e=d,n;if("click"==e&&(C&&a.metaKey||!C&&a.ctrlKey||2==a.which||null==a.which&&4==a.button||a.shiftKey))e="clickmod";else{var h;h=a.which||a.keyCode||a.key;da&&3==h&&(h=13);if(13!=h&&32!=h)h=!1;else{var l=y(a);n=(l.getAttribute("role")||l.type||l.tagName).toUpperCase();var g;(g="keydown"!=a.type)||("getAttribute"in l?(g=(l.getAttribute("role")||l.tagName).toUpperCase(),g=!G(l)&&("COMBOBOX"!=g||"INPUT"!=g)&&!l.isContentEditable):g=!1,g=!g);(g=g||a.ctrlKey||
a.shiftKey||a.altKey||a.metaKey||F(l)&&32==h)||((g=l.tagName in ea)||(g=l.getAttributeNode("tabindex"),g=null!=g&&g.specified),g=!(g&&!l.disabled));g?h=!1:(l="INPUT"!=l.tagName.toUpperCase()||l.type,g=!(n in E)&&13==h,h=(0==E[n]%h||g)&&!!l)}h&&(e="clickkey")}l=a.srcElement||a.target;h=J(e,a,l,"",null);var p;for(n=l;n&&n!=this;n=n.__owner||n.parentNode){p=c=n;g=e;var q=p.__jsaction;if(!q){var w=K(p,"jsaction");if(w){q=v[w];if(!q){for(var q={},A=w.split(ka),B=0,z=A?A.length:0;B@-webkit-keyframes gb__a{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}}@keyframes gb__a{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}}#gbsfw{min-width:400px;overflow:visible}.gb_Jb,#gbsfw.gb_g{display:block;outline:none}#gbsfw.gb_qa iframe{display:none}.gb_Kb{padding:118px 0;text-align:center}.gb_Lb{background:no-re

Answer (score -2):

the file image name is encrypted in php base64, you will have a hard time decrypting it, good luck!

Comment: Sorry, but the name of the image is not encrypted and base-64 is not a PHP technology...and base64 encoding is NOT hard to "decrypt" (decode).

Comment: Base-64 is not encryption, and decoding it is trivial: http://base64.sourceforge.net/